# Moving image in UIImageView Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

I have 5 different UIImageViews named Obstacle 1 through 5. I made a UIImageView array so it would be easier to store and access them all at once since I'm rarely only accessing one at a time. I'm trying to change the coordinates of the images, and the coordinates are changing, I've tested that to make sure. My problem is, while the coordinates are changing, the image isn't moving from its original position.

```
Obstacles[i].center = CGPointMake(tempNum+(i*125), RandomPosition);
```

I'm using this ^ to change where the image is. This was all working fine before I tried putting the images into an array. Also,

```
Obstacles[i].hidden = YES;      Obstacles[i].hidden = NO;
```

no longer works either.

UPDATE:
Declaration

```
UIImageView *Obstacles[5];
IBOutlet UIImageView *Obstacle1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Obstacle2;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Obstacle3;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Obstacle4;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Obstacle5;
```

Adding to Array

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    Obstacles[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Obstacle%i", i+1]]];
}
```

Comment: Post all the code which creates UIImageViews and places them into array and onto the screen. There is nothing wrong with this two lines alone.

Comment: @user3537411 I added what you asked for

Comment: Try creating an NSMutableArray called Obstacles instead of UIImageView *Obstacles[5];

Comment: May be you need to do this inside the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have created your array like this

```
UIImageView *Obstacles[5];
```

Instead use NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *Obstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And in the for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    [Obstacles addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Obstacle%i", i+1]]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Adding to Array code does't make sense. You not adding your Obstacles UIImageView's, but instead create the new ones. Try initialize your array like this:

```
UIImageView *Obstacles[5] = {Obstacle1, Obstacle2, Obstacle3, Obstacle4, Obstacle5};
```

If all five of this UIImageViews properly linked in InterfaceBuilder, then changing it's position like

```
Obstacles[i].center = CGPointMake(tempNum+(i*125), RandomPosition);
```

should work.

But there is a little help from having an array, if you still have this name-indexed variables.

If you have array of views, then you probably should't use Interface Builder anymore. Try creating them in code, manually adding them to superview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *obstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        UIView *obstacle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*100, 50, 50)];
        obstacle.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [obstacles addObject:obstacle];
        [self.view addSubview:obstacle];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        UIView *obstacle = obstacles[i];
        obstacle.center = CGPointMake(tempNum+(i*125), RandomPosition);
    }
}
```